# Max Buffer Size when calling Native methods

Tags: c#, interop, arrays

I have a C# program calling an existing C image library DLL using P/Invoke.

Is it possible there is a limit in the size of buffers than can be effectively marshalled?

I am calling a function where I pass a pointer to an InputBuffer, its size and an OutputBuffer like this :

```
cmsDoTransform(xform, inputBitmapBytesRGB, outputBitmapBytesCMYK, TotalPixels);
```

While experimenting with this code, I kept receiving MemoryAccessViolation errors?

So I started working with really small RGB images at sizes of 1x1 pixels, 2x2, 4x4, 8x8, 16x16 up to 64x64 and everything worked, all of a sudden, no more error messages. Couldn't be happier.

Confident, I went back to my original RGB test image of 364x288 pixels. That didn't work? Back to MemoryAccessViolations?

So I reduced the image size down from 364x288 to 288x288 to 256x256 until it "passed", at 128x128, resulting in an image size of 49,512 bytes.

So, the TotalPixels parameter in the above function call became 128x128 or 16,384. It seems to be about the "maximum" number the .NET marshaller will accept as a buffer size? Does that make sense?

Is there an upper limit, in .NET, that I can't go above in the humble kinds of image processing I'm doing?

Comment: Make sure the index to the byte[] is a ulong and not an integer.

Answer (score -1):

Egg on my face...

Turns out I was setting buffer sizes incorrectly.

I was using this code :

```
Byte[] Input = new byte[1024];
Byte[] Output = new byte[1024];
UInt32 pixels = 1024;    
cmsDoTransform(xform, Input, Output, pixels);
```

When I should have been using this code :

```
Byte[] Input = new byte[1024 x 3]; // To allow for RGB = 3 bytes/pixel
Byte[] Output = new byte[1024 x 4]; // To allow for CMYK = 4 bytes/pixel
UInt32 pixels = 1024; // Correct number of pixels
cmsDoTransform(xform, Input, Output, pixels);
```

I completely missed this vital distinction and wasted days looking for my mistake. I advised the developer to consider adding some code snippet in the documentation for the future...